# docmd.TransferSpreadsheet Access --> Excel //// specify destination worksheet AND range

Tags: ms-access, vba, etl

I have to write some Access VBA to export data from an Access query into a specific range of cells in an Excel document that has several worksheets.

I am having trouble finding the right way to specify the **worksheet AND range**.

Here is what I have so far:

```
docmd.TransferSpreadsheet(TransferType:=acExport, SpreadsheetType:=acSpreadsheetTypeExcel8, TableName:=qry_Main, _
    FileName:="c:\test.xlsm", _
    HasFieldNames:=False, _
    Range:="Main!J9:J10")
```

The broken piece is `Range:="Main!J9:J10"`

What's the proper way to make this reference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use CopyFromRecordset and automation:

```
Sub XLTrans()
''Reference: Microsoft ActiveX Data Object x.x Library
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim xl As Object ''Excel.Application
Dim wb As Object ''Workbook

Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

''Pick one
''1. New book
Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Add

''2. Existing book
Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Open("z:\docs\book1.xlsx")

''Connection relevant for 2007 or 2010
rs.Open "MyTableOrQuery", CurrentProject.AccessConnection

wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(4, 5).CopyFromRecordset rs

xl.Visible = True

End Sub
```

Note that this will not include column headings, but you can add them as well, for example:

```
For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(3, i + 5) = rs(i).Name
Next
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this out and let you know. +1 for now.

Comment: How would I be able to transfer Access data into an existing Excel workbook? I have a path to the Excel file. It seems like your solution creates a new Workbook, which is not what I need to do.

Comment: You can use the same idea to open a workbook. I have added a note.

Answer (score 2):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff844793.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa141565(v=office.10).aspx

You cannot use RANGE for exporting:
"
Range  Optional Variant. A string expression that's a valid range of cells or the name of a range in the spreadsheet. This argument applies only to importing. Leave this argument blank to import the entire spreadsheet. **When you export to a spreadsheet, you must leave this argument blank**. If you enter a range, the export will fail.

"

Comment: ah, this teaches me that i should take my time when reading MSDN ;) +1 for pointing out.